# Is it safe to focus on Agya chakra casually?

Tags: meditation, agya-chakra

To divert myself from daily thoughts I used to focus my mind on incoming and outgoing breath casually. Casually means whenever I am feeling like to focus like before going to sleep or whenever I am taking a break from my work to calm my mind. I am doing this without any Guru and anyone's guidance. I have assumed that its totally safe to focus on breathing whenever we want.

Recently I got to know a meditation technique that involves focusing on [Agya chakra](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ajna). Out of this I got to know the speciality and power of Agya chakra.

So can I casually focus on Agya chakra the way I was focusing on breathing in situations like while taking rest, while taking a break from work or while on bed before going to sleep?

Is it safe to focus on Agya chakra casually?

Comment: Yes. Ajna Chakra is notoriously difficult to activate. You can casually focus on that Chakra.

Comment: @PradipGangopadhyay: Can you answer https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/q/55912/15729 ?